# regex pattern to match command

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to make a addressee book program. I am making a command line program with 4 commands -L, -A, -C, -D to lookup, add, change, or delete contacts from the addressee book. I am using re to create a pattern to match the input the user enters to a certain command. I am having problems with the regex pattern for the add command. The command requires a  [name] and [email] to be entered along with a identifier for the command -a. and then is passed to the add() function to add the contact to the addressee book dictionary to be written to a file. this is what I have so far for the regex pattern.

```
add_regex = re.compile(r'''
    ([a-z]+)    #name
    \s          #whitespace
    ((\w+)      #first local part
    ([\._])?        #seperator
    (\w+)?      #second local part
    ([\._])?        #seperator
    (\w+)?      #third local part
    @           #single at sign
    \w+     #domain
    [.]     #period sepeorator
    \w{2,3}$)   #top level domain
    \s          #whitespace
    (-a)        # cmd
    ''', re.I | re.VERBOSE)
```

The regex gets it right when I remove the #cmd and #name portion of the pattern. and matches the email. but after I add them back it fails to match the input im not sure why anybody who can help pls do.
EDIT:
The input I have been testing is

```
keith keith.t.gill@gmail.com -a
```

and getting None on the regex search

Comment: can you give some example input? name is only first name without capital letters?

Comment: remove the $ from top level domain? its not end of line if you writ -a after it

Comment: I just figured it out thank you I feel dumb smh. @trigonom